# array manipulation help in php making phrases

Tags: php

I will have four word list arrays.

```
$array1 = array('red','blue','green');//it can have more elements

$array2 = array('ball','radio','bat');

$array3 = array('free','$10','bonus','2free');

$array4 = array('Ny','california');
```

using these 4 arrays of words which can have 0 to any no of elements in them for example above the out put needs to be

```
red ball free Ny

red ball free california

red ball $10 Ny

red ball $10 california

red ball bonus Ny

red ball bonus california

red ball 2free Ny

red ball 2free california

red radio free Ny
```

..................................similarly for all elements possibly in array

it was easy for me up to 2 but with 4 arrays i am a bit confused to achieve it.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is with nested loops:

```
$array1 = array('red','blue','green');
$array2 = array('ball','radio','bat');
$array3 = array('free','$10','bonus','2free');
$array4 = array('Ny','california');

for ($i = 0, $maxi = count($array1); $i < $maxi; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0, $maxj = count($array2); $j < $maxj; $j++) {
        for ($k = 0, $maxk = count($array3); $k < $maxk; $k++) {
            for ($l = 0, $maxl = count($array4); $l < $maxl; $l++) {
                echo '<p>' . $array1[$i] . ' ' . $array2[$j] . ' ' . $array3[$k] . ' ' . $array4[$l] . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try it but what if any of the middle array does not have any element in it that is count is 0??

Comment: If any of the arrays are empty, it won't output anything. Probably the simplest way to ensure there's output in that case is to check each array before the loop and, if it's empty, add a single element with a space to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as $first)
  foreach($array2 as $second)
    foreach($array3 as $third)
      foreach($array4 as $fourth)
      {
        echo $first." ".$second." ".$third." ".$fourth;
      }
```